# How to do a project/modify a existing project in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

I have no idea/experience in VB programming. One of my client bought me his old project which need to be modified. He says it is written in Visual Basic and no idea which version.

So how can i carry ON to work with this project by identifying the version
And what other components do i require to do the programming and user interface.

I already have Visual studio 2010 with me. So can i do my work using this software or i have to go for anything else...

Any suggestions....?

Regards 
ParshTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the earlier VS version. If the project was developed in earlier version of VS, you can upgrade to VS 2010 easily but otherwise you need to get hands on specific VS version.

Similarly if the project have database functionality or crystal report or any other external dependencies, you need to check their versions. You need to install the components according to these versions. Specify your versions and i'll tell you what to use for further development.

Comment: How to check the earlier VS version...? Yes the project has database functionality too....

Comment: Well, your project must have a .sln ( Solution ) file. If you have a VS 2010 installed and even if you have greater version .sln, there is a numberon .sln icon. You can recognize version from that or try to find version in .sln files properties.

After opening project, explore the project to find database information. First try to find VS Version

Comment: I got a .sln file but i did not notice any number written on the icon nor any version specified in the files properties too....

Comment: Are you sure you have at least VS 2010 installed. Otherwise file will not show specific icon

Comment: Yes VS 2010 is installed...   I am able to open some .vb files. When i tried to open .sln file using VS it asked me to keep back up of existing files and converted my files to something...   I dont know what exactly it did but right now i have backup files generated....

Comment: Well, if the VS tells to take backup, its a good sign. This is actually a upgrade process. VS will take backup of OLD version files and upgrade project for VS 2010. GO ahead, take backup and continue and you should be able to open project in VS2010

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "myproject", "myproject\myproject.vbproj", "{8C04867E-3CA4-481A-A664-5DF8AB6A7854}"
EndProject

Comment: This is the 1st 3 lines of .sln file from the backup

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "myproject", "myproject\myproject.vbproj", "{8C04867E-3CA4-481A-A664-5DF8AB6A7854}"
EndProject

Comment: This is the 1st 3 lines of .sln file from the current project folder

Comment: So is that means the version of the project is VS 2008 and now it is upgraded to VS 2010....?

Comment: Yes. Now you should be able to view files in **Solution Explorer**

Now explore the project and find database related information

Comment: Yes i can view the files in Solution explorer...    How to explore the project...?

Comment: Explore means open the forms and try to find the database connection. Can you post **Solution Explorer Snapshot** here ?

Comment: I got the database information from app.config file as below

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.myprojectConnectionString"
            connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=myprojectdb"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: That means the project uses MySQL database. If you don't have MySQL database installed then install it, configure it, change the connection string acc to that configuration and you are good to go

Comment: Mysql is installed already and configurations are also set up....   So now i can continue with VB 2010 right....?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Just Run the project and try to insert or retrieve data from database

Comment: Hey, the question you asked already solved, isn't it ? Close this question and ask new question for different problem. 

We should not discuss other problems than the question asked,

Comment: Ok i thought something went wrong when i converted the code from VS 2008 to VS 2010...   Anyways thanx a lot for the guidance...